# Python Recursive function from loop

Tags: python, loops, recursion, binary

I created a function that prints all binary sequences n bits long:

```
def print_binary_sequences(n):
    if n<1:
        return
    for i in range(2**n):
        s = bin(i)[2:]
        s = "0" * (n-len(s)) + s
        print(s)
```

it works very well, but i completely missed on the task which was to do this using recursion. I have been trying for quite some time now to create a recursive function out of this and failed. any help?

Comment: An n-bit binary string is either a '0' or a '1' followed by an (n-1)-bit binary string.  Turn this idea into a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want is to `print` the combinations, you could do something like this:

```
def binary_rec(n, data=''):
    if len(data) == n:
        print data
    else:
        binary_rec(n, data + '0')
        binary_rec(n, data + '1')
```

Basically, it will start with an empty solution `data = ''`, and it will recursively call itself with 2 new solucions `data = data + '0'` and `data = data + '1'`. It will recursively explore both options until the stored result (`data`) has length `n`.

```
>>> binary_rec(2)
00
01
10
11
```

If what you want is to `return` all the possible combinations for future use, then that will require some minor changes (you can easily change the above logic).

Additionally, you can easily modify the above to return lists of `0` and `1` (i.e. `data=[]` init param and `data + [0]` updates).